# WiX remove namespace in root element

Tags: xml, wix

How can I remove the xmlns attribute from a root element in WiX?

My XML file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
```

I tried it with util:XmlFile 
but that didn't work

```
<util:XmlFile 
Id='deleteTextInsideConfigurationNode'
File='filename'
Action='deleteValue' 
Name="xmlns"
ElementPath="//*[\[]local-name()='configuration'[\]]"
SelectionLanguage="XPath"
Sequence='2' />
```

util:XmlConfig also didn't work

```
<util:XmlConfig
Id='deleteTextInsideConfigurationNode'
File='filename'
Action="delete"
Node="value"
On="install"
Name="xmlns"
ElementPath="/configuration"
Sequence='2' />
```

Comment: I think your Xpath query is wrong, in the XMLConfig config can you change the ElementPath to "//configuration"

Comment: `xmlns` is not an attribute. Removing the namespace would change the meaning of the document. Why do you want and need to do that?

Comment: This namespace was used in a previous version of the program. I don't need it anymore in the current version. The installer tries to find old installations and copies this files to the new installlocation. Then I need to remove the namespace element. At the moment I managed to do this with a custom action.

Comment: As I said before, that is a very radical transformation of an XML document. XmlFile and XmlConfig are designed to make point changes so I don't think they can do it. BTW-They use custom actions, too. Of course, their custom actions are already tested in thousands of installers. If no one else finds an answer, you should post yours and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a managed custom action in C# that removes the namespace. I run it after SchedXmlConfig.

That worked for me. Probably not possible to do this with XmlConfig or XmlFile.